# How can I remove everything except last n bytes from the file in Linux?

Tags: linux, files, rm, delete, tomcat

I've a Tomcat server where logs are stored as `catalina.out`. It's a pretty huge file and causes troubles a lot of times.

Because of it taking too much space, other servers have to stop involunatarily. I want at least a duct tape fix to this issue, so that I don't have to bother with tickets that are just deleting `catalina.out` and restarting the server.

I am not sure, but its 1 day logs are over 5 GB. So, say I want to make a [cron job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) that deletes files older than a day or the last 5 GB from that file. What command would work here?

Is it recommended to solve this problem this way? Or are there better approaches?

Comment: The first point to address is to investigate why your Catalina log file is growing so rapidly. Are you running with debug enabled in a production environment, for example?

Comment: Or you can modify log parameters to automatically rotate log files after, for example, a day, or after exceeded some size, say, 1GB. But it is depend on which logging framework are you using.

Comment: @roaima debug mode is  enabled.  plus all days logs are merged into a single log file, that's why that is so big.

Comment: Don't run in debug mode on a production server. If you're simply throwing away the log file data then you don't need it, so don't generate it

Comment: i think your reply is fantastic solution to this problem. I've barely got anything by looking at catalina.out logs. But I want logs some day though maybe.

Comment: @JanMarek we don't use any log rotate frameworks as I know. We manually delete them when the space is full. It's very funny and unorganized.

Comment: "_It's very funny and unorganized_" - this could be your opportunity to recommend professional best practice

Comment: @roaima I'm seeking for best practices. Currently I can see logrotate. 30% of our tickets will reduce if we follow best practices.

Answer (score 5):

`catalina.out` should be mostly *empty*, meaning the application intercepts all errors and handles them itself, possibly logging them elsewhere as configured. But more often than not, nothing such is done and `catalina.out` is considered as *the* application logs. This causes problems because by default Tomcat doesn't rotate this file.

The better approach to truncating the file (and beside fixing the application) is to have rotation in place for `catalina.out`. This might already be provided by the specific packaged installation (eg: CentOS7's tomcat 7 is/was shipped with proper `catalina.out` log rotation in place), or with a recent enough version of tomcat as described in [Bug 64430](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64430) whose [fix](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/attachment.cgi?id=37242&action=diff) has been integrated in newer Tomcat and backported to Tomcat >= 7.0.105, >= 8.5.56 and >= 9.0.36:

> Example (all one line)
>
> ```
> CATALINA_OUT_CMD="/usr/bin/rotatelogs -f $CATALINA_BASE/logs/catalina.out.%Y-%m-%d.log 86400"
> ```

---

Rotated files should be further handled with [`logrotate`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/logrotate.8.html) or an equivalent specialized tool.

Now to strictly answer the question, or at least the part about handling the single `catalina.out` file.
OP writes both:

> How to remove everything except last n bytes from the file in Linux?

=> keep the end

> deletes [...] the last 5GB from that file

=> keep the start

### Keep the start

Thus removing the end. Even if removing the *end* of a log rather than the *start* of a log is a bad idea:

POSIX [`truncate(2)`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/truncate.html):

> NAME
>
> truncate - truncate a file to a specified length
>
> [...]
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> The truncate() function shall cause the regular file named by path to
> have a size which shall be equal to length bytes.

Which has its `truncate(1)` command implementation. For [GNU truncate](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/truncate-invocation.html#truncate-invocation) (along GNU `stat(1)`) that would be used like this in shell (one has to check the file is greater than 5GiB first or its size would be increased instead). Keeping 5GiB:

```bash
if [ $(stat -c %s catalina.out) -gt $((5*1024*1024*1024)) ]; then
    truncate -s $((5*1024*1024*1024)) catalina.out
fi
```

### Keep the end

Thus deleting the start of the file. It's possible on Linux and adequate filesystem (eg: Ext4, XFS ...) to do this without involving any copy of data, using [`fallocate(1)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/fallocate.1.html) (with additional Linux-only features):

> `-p`, `--punch-hole`
>
> Deallocates space (i.e., creates a hole) in the byte range starting at
> offset and continuing for length bytes.

This doesn't involve any copy of data, but requires this to be block-aligned (so usually 4096 bytes-aligned). One can always keep the end of the file, a bit like a ring buffer, without any copy cost. This could be used like this (extra computation is needed to align to a 4096 multiple):

```bash
oldsize=$(stat -c %s catalina.out) || exit 1

if [ $oldsize -gt $((5*1024*1024*1024)) ]; then
    holesize=$(( (oldsize-5*1024*1024*1024)/4096*4096 ))
    fallocate --punch-hole --length "$holesize" catalina.out
fi
```

`--punch-hole` (freeing the disk space by making the file sparse and keeping its apparent size) is used rather than `--collapse-range` ("moving" remaining data to the start reducing the size) to avoid disruption of the ongoing output appended to `catalina.out` by Tomcat, else Tomcat should be stopped before and restarted after.

Comment: will take me few weeks to understand that bash script. lots of new commands i've not studied yet. looks like dreaded c programming to me :)

Comment: I was worried that the numbers could approach bash arithmetic limits, but it's fine : https://superuser.com/a/1030129/174998

Answer (score 2):

```
tail catalina.out > catalina.new
rm catalina.out
mv catalina.new catalina.out
```

Then you have to restart or reload tomcat to append logs to new file (it still has opened file descriptor of old catalina.out file, which are now removed).

`tail` (from [coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/)) has these parameters:

> `-c`, `--bytes=[+]NUM` output the last `NUM` bytes; or use `-c +NUM` to output starting with byte `NUM` of each file
>
> `-n`, `--lines=[+]NUM` output the last `NUM` lines, instead of the last 10; or use `-n +NUM` to output starting with line `NUM`

For other parameters, please, consult [`man tail`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html).

Comment: Considering that `logrotate` is very common in today's Linux, when not use that to limit the file space usage? Also when considering that the process will continue to write to the file being opened, why not `mv catalina.out catalina.old && tail catalina.old > catalina.out` (The process will continue to write to `catalina.old` until restarted)?

Comment: I use `> catalina.out` To empty the logs, was looking for something better. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Instead of treating the symptom, treat the disease.

As others have mentioned, "proper logging" will save you from this. But proper logging involves the development team, a develop-test-release cycle, etc. and you probably want to fix your problem **now**.

The reason `catalina.out` is filling-up is because the application is writing to `stdout`, probably with `System.out.println` or similar. That's not great and should be fixed over time.

Luckily, Tomcat has a band-aid for you. All you have to do is edit the file `META-INF/context.xml` in the application (or, wherever your `<Context>` is defined, possibly in `conf/server.xml`, or `conf/[engine]/[host]/[app].xml`) and add this to your `<Context>`:

```
swallowOutput="true"
```

Search https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html for "swallowOutput" to see the description.

That will take everything from your application and put it into the application-specific log file, which *is* rotatable.

Then you can just delete whole-logs after a few days, etc. instead of playing games with trying to "shorten" files.